# Why are those quotations there and how can I remove them?

Tags: javascript, fetch, quotations

When I run the following code:

```
const root = document.querySelector('#root3');

async function fetchData(userId) {
  const response = await fetch(`https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10`);
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);
  console.log(data.results);
  data.results.map(item => {
    root.append(`<li><img src=${item.picture.thumbnail}></li>`);
  });
}

fetchData();
```

The result is this:

[image]

Why are those quotations there? and how can I get rid of them?

Comment: Java != JavaScript

Comment: You aren't "appending an element" you are "appending a string". I think you might be looking for something like `appendChild` where some HTML gets added to an existing element.

Answer (score 0):

OK. You cannot use append in JavaScript.
One solution, which is working is the following:

```
root.innerHTML += `<li><img src=${item.picture.thumbnail}></li>`;
```